# Git Rebasing Branch Commits, When It Already Has Separate Merged Branch Commits In It?

Tags: git, github, version-control

Typically my Git work flow is like so:

```
git add --all
git commit
git push -u origin branch/name
git merge master
```

From here I make more changes, and repeat the above.

When I am looking at my commit history for the branch, I have commit messages not only for my branch, but also from the merge via master. I want to be able to rebase and squash commits for just my branch. So the last 10 commits would be my branch specific commits, and without all other commits from a merge into my branch. I wouldn't mind if Git gave me a commit for a merge from another branch that was one commit that denoted a merge from blank, but I am not seeing that.

Is there a common solution to this? I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you sort of answered your own question in the title, but one way to avoid having the merge commit appear would be to *rebase* your local branch on the remote `master`.  Change your workflow to this:

```
git add --all
git commit -m 'Now I'm rebasing...woohoo'
git rebase origin/master

# resolve merge conflicts, which may occur at the replay of each commit

git push --force -u branch/name
```

**Comments:**

The command `git rebase origin/master` will rebase your local branch (which may be anything related to `master`) on the remote `master`.  As each commit from your local branch is replayed, you may encounter a merge conflict.  After resolving the conflict, you can continue the rebase by typing `git rebase --continue`.

The command `git push --force -u branch/name` will *overwrite* the version of your local branch which exists on the remote.  This is required because, in the process of doing the rebase on `master`, you actually *rewrote* the history of your branch.